# Overlapping area of two circle's crossing it's center i.e., length of overlapping is greater than r of the circle. Circle's has equal area.

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

[image]

Let there be two circular coasters of equal area (and negligible height). The purpose of is to find how far the two coasters need to be moved on top of each other such that the area of the overlapping region is half the area of any one of the coasters.

Comment: The overlapping area is two [circular segments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_segment) so you want each one to be  one quarter of the area of a coaster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two circles have equal radius $r$, say. The area of the overlapping region is given by:

$$2 \cdot \left([\text{area of sector of angle $\alpha$}] - [\text{area of isoceles triangle with vertex angle $\alpha$}]\right).$$

The area of the aforementioned triangle is $\frac{1}{2}r^2 \sin \alpha$, and the area of the sector is $\frac{1}{2}r^2 \alpha$. Thus, we have that

$$\frac{1}{2}\pi r^2 = 2\left(\frac{1}{2}r^2 \alpha - \frac{1}{2}r^2 \sin \alpha\right),$$

and solving for $\alpha$ yields that $\alpha - \sin \alpha = \frac{\pi}{2}$, so $\alpha \approx 2.3$. Then, the desired distance is $2(r - r \cos(\alpha/2))$.

Comment: I need very detailed theory about this Ashvin, if possible can I have any link for the above area of overlapping?

Comment: There is no link that I have in mind, sorry... and let me also remark that there is no very detailed theory here. This is middle-school geometry, so you could consult any textbook on geometry for grade-school students.